# How do I do routing for something like {city}/pricing, {city}/how-it-works, etc. while loading the same template and dataset?

Tags: routing

I'm trying to set up a site for clients that have locations in multiple cities and who want to be able to display something specific to that location on certain pages. I would like to set up routes using the city name as a variable, followed by the page (i.e. `mysite.com/chicago/pricing`, `mysite.com/boston/pricing`, etc.), and have it route to the same section and template with all of that section's corresponding entry fields.

I was planning to grab the URL parameter as a variable that enables me to dynamically load content based on a simple string match for that variable. I want to do something like this

```
{% set location = matches[1] %}

{% if not location %}
  {% set selectedLocation = locations.defaultLocation %}
{% else %}
  {% set selectedLocation = location %}
{% endif %}

....

{% for plan in entry.pricingPlans %}
    {% if plan.location == selectedLocation %}
      ...
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I can route to the template itself just fine, but I don't get the data. Any suggestions on how best to achieve this? I'm not very PHP savvy and have only recently started getting to more advanced tasks in Craft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the problem you're not getting the segment from the URL?

`{% set locationSlugInUrl = craft.request.getSegment(1) %}` or `{% set locationSlugInUrl = craft.request.firstSegment %}` should do that for you.

Or you're not getting the entry? In which case you need to either specify the template in that section's settings or do something like `{% set entry = craft.entries.section('pricing').first %}` or whatever the section slug is (assuming it's a single).

And what kind of field is `entry.pricingPlans`? If it is a matrix field, what type of field is `plan.location`?

Comment: I was able to figure this out by using something like `{% set entry = craft.entries.section('pricing').first %}` if `entry` was null, that way I can handle cases where a user goes to `mysite.com/pricing` (where the section is passing the entry data) or `mysite.com/boston/pricing` (where I need to pull from `craft.entries.section`). Thanks.

Comment: Yep, sounds familiar.